# Spring data JPA repository order by condition

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Product entity which contains some attributes, I need to get the closest products to a given product depending on some criteria, the criteria are category, finish and production company.
I wrote this query

```
@Query("Select pr from Product pr ORDER BY (CASE WHEN (pr.category = :p.category) THEN 1 WHEN (pr.finish = :p.finish) THEN 2 WHEN (pr.productionCompany = :p.productionCompany) THEN 3 ELSE 4 ) LIMIT 5")
List<Product> findRecommendedProducts(@Param("p")Product p);
```

But this keeps giving me the following exception

```
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting "end", found ')'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `ELSE 4 END` to your query. I assume this is running on Oracle?

Comment: Actually I am using mysql but the error is gone and now I have another exception
 Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.